# Can Stack Exchange Data Explorer be used for non-Stack-Exchange (i.e. personal) data sets?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm on the hunt for a tool to expose data from an Sql Server database for templated queries. I've stumbled across the Stack Exchange Data Exporter and I'm wondering if it can satisfy my needs.

If I were to get local installation going, would I be able to point it at my own (i.e. nothing to do with Stack Exchange) data-sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I were to get local installation going, would I be able to point it at my own (i.e. nothing to do with StackExchange) data-sets?

Yes, though you would have to work at getting those into the tool and working for your data sets.

It really is geared towards Stack Exchange data, so you would need to work on the source code to make that happen - it is [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer).

Comment: Is this practically or theoretically?

Comment: Theoretically. The codebase is open source on github, so can be forked. https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer

Comment: You really shouldn't need any *changes* to just run queries on other types of data, it's just that some functionality won't work/be useful for non-Stack Exchange data.

Comment: @TimStone - please feel free to edit in any corrections and additional information. Made this CW.

Comment: I like how SE devs reference SO questions in their code https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/Migrations/035%20-%20Drop%20meaningless%20IsModerator%20from%20Users.sql That's a new kind of dogfooding for ya